# Let $f$ be a real function such that $f'(x) > 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$. Show that $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t^2)dx$ is three times differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying real analysis and came across this question:

**Let $f$ be a real function such that $f'(x) > 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t^2)dx$ is three times differentiable and calculate $g'(x),g''(x)$ and $g'''(x)$. Take advantage of the result to study, regarding concavity and inflections, of the graphic of g.**

So far what I've done is compute the derivatives of g. Let $u = t^2$, then $\dfrac{du}{2} = dt$. Following that

$$g(x) \ = \ \int_{0}^{x} f(t^2)dt \ = \ \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x^2} f(u)du.$$

By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have that

$$g'(x) = x \cdot f(x^2) \ ; \  \ g''(x) =  2x^2 \cdot f'(x^2)  + f(x^2)$$

$$\ \text{and} \ g'''(x) = 4x^3 \cdot f''(x^2) \ + \ 4x \cdot f'(x^2) \ + \ 2x \cdot f'(x^2).$$

My question is: **How can I find out the concavity or the inflection points of the graph of g if I don't have the information about f being positive or negative,  or the value of f(0)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, early on, you've already performed a key error:
$$
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
u = t^2 \implies \dd u = 2t \, \dd t 
$$
(Notice you missed the $t$.) It might be simpler to define
$$
g(x) = \int_0^x h(t) \, \dd t \text{ wherein } h(t) = f(t^2)
$$
and then one realizes that applying the fundamental theorem is a lot more straightforward. For instance,
$$
g'(x) = h(x) = f(x^2)
$$
If one insists upon the substitution, they get
$$
g(x) = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{x^2} \frac{f(u)}{\sqrt u} \, \dd u
$$
Then
$$
g'(x) = \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{f(x^2)}{\sqrt{x^2}} \right) \frac{\dd}{\dd x} x^2
$$
(bear in mind the chain rule), but we easily see that this matches up with the more basic calculation stated.

---

From here, finding $g''$ and $g'''$ is straightforward.

To find the points of inflection of $g$, you would use the standard test: that at a prospective point of inflection $x_0$, we would have $g''>0$ to the left of $x_0$, and $g''<0$ to the right of $x_0$ (or $g''<0$ and $g''>0$ respectively). If differentiable at $x_0$, we would have $g''(x_0) = 0$ as well.

You might have to make conjectures as to the behavior of $f$ in certain cases; this is a very open-ended question, and, yes, a good chunk of work could depend on how $f$ behaves.

Comment: In fact, I didn't realize that I made a mistake right at the beginning. I'm ashamed. Thank you so much for your answer. I will try the question again.